# Pegar valor referente ao select JS/PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, banco-de-dados

estou com dúvida.

Eu tenho um questionário onde o usuário irá avaliar alguns setores.
Eu tenho por exemplo:

```html
 <label>Higiene</label>
<select class="form-control" required >
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<label>Organização</label>
<select class="form-control" required >
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<label>Ambiente</label>
<select class="form-control" required >
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Eu sei que posso pegar o valor do select ao usar o name, mas o que eu quero é pegar também a palavra que está na label e conseguir referenciar para depois salvar no banco, para poder gravar no banco a nota que o usuário deu e para qual setor ele deu. Por exemplo:

SETOR ----- NOTA -----

Higiene      2

Organização  1

Ambiente     0

Comment: Mas ao nomear, por exemplo, o primeiro `<select>` como `name='higiene'` você já não saberá que essa avaliação é referente à higiene?

Comment: Mas ao enviar via POST, por exemplo $_POST['higiene'] eu pegaria só o valor do select, certo? Preciso de algum jeito colocar Higiene em alguma variável para poder gravar no banco, meu formulário tem vários selects, queria fazer de um jeito mais dinâmico.

Comment: `$_POST` é um array, você pode fazer o foreach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post"> 
<label for="higiene">Higiene</label>
<select name="higiene" id="higiene" class="form-control" required >
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<label for="organizacao">Organização</label>
<select name="organizacao" id="organizacao" class="form-control" required >
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<label for="ambiente">Ambiente</label>
<select name="ambiente" id="ambiente" class="form-control" required >
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Use a sintaxe foreach e switch. Veja nos 2 exemplos logo abaixo:

```
<?php

  if (!empty($_POST)) {

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
        {
    
            
            switch ($key) {
                case 'organizacao':
                    echo "Organização :". $value;
                    break;
                case 'ambiente':
                    echo "Ambiente :". $value;
                    break;
                case 'higiene':
                    echo "Higiene :". $value;
                    break;
            }           
        }
  }
```

Veja também neste exemplo, concatenando dentro do *switch*:

```
  if (!empty($_POST)) {

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
        {
            switch ($key) {
                case 'organizacao':
                    $bd .= "'SETOR'=Organização, 'NOTA'=$value ...";
                    
                    break;
                case 'ambiente':
                    
                    $bd .= "'SETOR'=Ambiente, 'NOTA'=$value ...";
                    break;
                case 'higiene':
                    
                    $bd = "'SETOR'=Higiene, 'NOTA'=$value ...";
                    break;
            }   
            
        }
  }
  
  echo $bd;
```

**O "resultado" do print(echo), será:** `'SETOR'=Higiene, 'NOTA'=1 ...'SETOR'=Organização, 'NOTA'=2 ...'SETOR'=Ambiente, 'NOTA'=1 ...`

Comment: Obrigado Fabiano!